# Cloud Storage - Usage and Impact

Tags: data-request

Looking for details on usage, adoption, impact, challenges on using public cloud storage platforms example Google Drive, Microsoft Skydrive, Box, Dropbox and so.

Comment: You should be much more specific. Say exactly what measures you want, and specify the units for each measure. Cheers!